# Binding svg attribute with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I have some element in my SVG like:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    ...
    <svg ...>
        <line id="line1" x1="140" x2={{x2}} y1="10" y2="10" transform="{{rotate}}"/>
        ...
    </svg>
</div>
```

where `x2` is the end coordinate and rotate is in form `rotate(...,...,...)`, which are all string type. This line element does not change when the value changes. Neither does it rotate nor show the `x2` attribute correctly.

By the way, the date binding is programmed correctly, as I also use `{{x2}}` in a `<p>` tag and it is shown correctly.

Comment: BTW, it would help if you were more specific about which version of AngularJS you are using. I'm presuming that you are using [Version 1](https://angularjs.org/). I'm also wondering if you really need to alter x2 since you are rotating the line.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I know this is quite old, but stumbled upon this issue once again, so thought I would provide the correct approach. In newer Angular you need to use this syntax:

```
<line id="line1" [attr.x1]="140" [attr.x2]="x2" [attr.y1]="10" [attr.y2]="10" [attr.transform]="rotate"/>
```

Comment: perfectly works in Angular 8!
Thanks! I have used next: 
`[attr.d]="gauge[65]"`

Comment: how can i set `stroke-dasharray` attribute because it have 2 values. what i have tried is: `[attr.stroke-dasharray]="circle.rev_percentage + '  ' + circle.rev_percentage - 100"`. its shoeing `NaN`;

Comment: I believe that would be `attr.strokeDasharray` or `attr.stroke.dasharray` have you tried any of those? I guess this doesn't help that much, 2 years later :)

Answer (score 4):

To control the svg's line-transform attribute, you need to use the `ng-attr-myAttr` approach, where `myAttr` in this case is your svg line's `x2` and `transform` attributes. For example, you could write this svg line as follows:

`<line id="line1" x1="140" ng-attr-x2={{x2}} y1="10" y2="10" ng-attr-transform="{{rotation}}" />`